# Source code or detailed explanation of "WKS" virtual memory compression algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, memory-management, data-compression, virtual-memory, cache

I've been trying to find information on various program data virtual memory compression algorithms that are in the "WK" family of algorithms. So far, I've been successful with the "WKdm" compression algorithm ( see [here](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/usenix99/full_papers/wilson/wilson.pdf) and [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.22.5/iokit/Kernel/WKdm.h.auto.html) ). The other algorithm that I'm interested in is a variation on the "WKdm" algorithm called the "WKS" algorithm. The paper in which it was first introduced can be found [here](https://terpconnect.umd.edu/~barua/matt-compress-tr.pdf). The problem is that the paper does not describe the algorithm in any detail and just gives a very brief high-level overview of some major differences with the "WKdm" algorithm without any in-depth technical description. I have only found one other reference in the literature to the "WKS" algorithm. I've also contacted the author of the algorithm but I've yet to receive a response.

Does anyone know the details of the "WKS" algorithm?

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

jdb2

Comment: Source code is off-topic here.

Comment: Google suggests *Paul R. Wilson* and *Scott F. Kaplan* for the WK, and *Yannis Smaragdakis* - you could have disclosed more of what you tried. I get stuck at [Compressed Caching in Virtual Memory Systems - Compression Algorithm Implementations](http://web.archive.org/web/20000823031019/http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/oops/compressed-caching/index.html) not listing *WKS*.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Source code may be off-topic, but at least for the "WKdm" algorithm, the Apple open-source code is one of the **only** sources of information on details crucial to the "WKdm" algorithm that were left out of the original paper. Also, as for the "WKS" algorithm, if the details of the algorithm can **only** be obtained from a source code implementation, then I can't see how that would be off-topic.

Comment: @greybeard Huh? I provided all the relevant links in my original post. For the "WKdm" algorithm, the second hit of the google search "wkdm memory compression algorithm" corresponds to the first link in my original post. For the "WKS" algorithm, the third hit of the google search "wks memory compression algorithm" corresponds to the third link I provided.

Comment: Huh. The general idea is to include information [*in the posts here*](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and use references and hyperlinks for details and, errm, reference.